# Como saber se existe linha selecionada no DBGrid?

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-xe6, object-pascal

Como posso saber se existe linha selecionada no meu DBGrid. Neste caso abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ponteiro está selecionado no dataset, mas eu queria saber quando o grid está dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso seria apenas se ele a linha está "pintada", se sim como saber? Tentei `DBGrid.Focused` e `DBGrid.SelectedRows.CurrentSelected`  mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo que neste caso devemos trabalhar com `grid`, seria então:

```
DBGDados.Columns.Grid.Focused
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, seria se ela estiver pintada, porem o primeiro registro ja vem selecionado.

quando quero verificar realizo dessa forma

```
if query.FieldByName(campo_id).AsInteger >= 1 then
   // procedimento para realizar chamada de tela entre outros...
```

CUIDADO!!

```
DBGDados.Columns.Grid.Focused
```

Verifica se o foco esta no grid!!

Caso queira alterar a cor da linha selecionada tem este codigo

```
  if not odd(qyrBuscaBanco.RecNo) then            // deixa grid zebrado
     begin
        if not (gdSelected in State) then
           begin
              dbgrdBanco.Canvas.Brush.Color := clMoneyGreen;
              dbgrdBanco.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
              dbgrdBanco.DefaultDrawDataCell(rect,Column.Field,state);
           end;
     end;

  with dbgrdBanco do                 // pinta a linha selecionada
       begin
          if DataSource.DataSet.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert, dsBrowse] then 
             begin
                if (Rect.Top = TStringGrid(dbgrdBanco).CellRect( DataCol ,TStringGrid(dbgrdBanco).Row).Top)
                    or( gdSelected in State)  then
                   begin
                      Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
                      Canvas.Brush.Color := [COR PARA A LINHA SELECIONADA];
                      DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect,Column.Field,State)
                   end;
             end;
       end;
```